# Logrotate behaviour for rules defined in multiple places

Tags: linux, logrotate

I need your help to understand logrotate behaviour .

`logrotate.conf`:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

In the `logrotate.d` directory, I have for example one file called `consul-log`:

```
/var/log/consul {
    size 500M
    missingok
    rotate 0
    compress
    notifempty
    copytruncate
}
```

In the `/var/lib/logrotate.status`, file I can see these lines (related to the consul log file):

```
logrotate state -- version 2
"/var/log/consul" 2016-1-25
```

My question is:

1. If I have `rotate 4` inside `logrotate.conf`, but I have `rotate 0` inside `logrotate.d/consul-log`, will logrotate use `rotate 0` or `rotate 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your question:

> If I have `rotate 4` inside `logrotate.conf`, but I have `rotate 0` inside `logrotate.d/consul-log`, will logrotate use `rotate 0` or `rotate 4`?

`logrotate.conf` is the configuration file for the systemwide changes and any other configuration file which you  create in the `logrotate.d` folder will be overriden.

Because of this directive:

```
# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

Answer (score 1):

For `/var/log/consul`, it will use `rotate 0`. Quote from the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html):

> Each configuration file can set global options (local definitions override global ones, and later definitions override earlier ones) and specify logfiles to rotate.

In your case, `rotate 0` is both local and later.